# Register, Login, Logout with django class based views

Tags: python-3.8, django-3.1

I am trying to make an authentication system with django class based views

What I have tried so far:

This is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views import generic

from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

from django.urls import reverse_lazy



class UserCreationView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

This is forms.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'input', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'})
    
    }
```

This the urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import UserCreationView


urlpatterns = [
    
    path('register/', UserCreationView.as_view(), name = 'register'),

]
```

Other urls.py file(urls.py file present in project folder)

```
    path('users/', include(urls)),
    path('users/', include('authentication.urls')),
```

**The problem with this code is** Whenever I login I can still login and register by going to the login url(login url in this case:`http://localhost:8000/users/login/`), How can I restrict user to log in again

Comment: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-class-based-auth-views

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the default LoginView() class on

```
django.contrib.auth import views
```

has a boolean attribute called

```
redirect_authenticated_user
```

And I believe this is what you are looking for.

Just look for `class LoginView` in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/ and you will see it.